# Executar uma função e se demorar mais que x segundos da erro - React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react, react-native, jsx

Boa tarde!

Fiz uma função que busca os dados de um JSON na Web, porém queria envolve-lo numa função que se demorasse mais que por exemplo 10 segundos explodisse um erro na tela, atualmente a página só fica em branco, só explode o erro se eu mudar a url do get

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.setState({loading:true})
    setTimeout(()=>{
        axios
        .get('LINK DO JSON')
        .then(response =>{
            const {dados} = response.data;
            //colocando no state
            this.setState({
                pessoas: dados,
                loading: false,

            })
        }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                error: true,
            })      
        })
    },8000)    
}
```

Se ele demorar mais que 10 segundos queria q desse um erro, mas só da o erro se eu mexo ali  no link do JSON e coloco um inexistente. O setTimeOut fica carregando o loading por esses "8 segundos - 8000 miliseconds'' , mas depois fica em branco e queria q explodisse um erro ao inves disso

Código que chama depois:

```
render() {      
    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>       
        {
            this.state.loading 
            ? <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='#97c19a'/>
            : this.state.error
            ? <View> 
                  <Text style={styles.error}>Ops... Algo deu errado =(</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.error2}>Tente recarregar a página!</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.error2}>Se o problema persistir, contate a TI!</Text>
              </View>
            : <ListaDePessoas pessoas={this.state.pessoas} onPressItem={pageParams => {this.props.navigation.navigate('PeopleDetailPage', pageParams)}}/>
        }       
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Comment: tente utilizar a chamada do axios sem o `setTimeout` e substituindo o `axios.get('LINK DO JSON')` por `axios.get('LINK DO JSON', {timeout: 10000})`

Comment: Até que funcionou, mas quando eu coloco 10 segundos por exemplo, [forçando da o erro] o loading("activity indicator") fica menos que 10 segundos e a tela novamente fica cinza/branco, somente com o header a amostra. Isso o usuário não entenderia o que aconteceu, mas quando coloco 1 segundo no timeout, funciona normalmente. E também pra poder pegar esse link do json o usuário tem q estar em um wifi proprio se não ele nao consegue ver os dados, não sei se isso tem a ver

Comment: Em seus testes a requisição retorna sucesso ou erro?

Comment: Retorna uma pagina em cinza, que é a cor do meu background, mas não da erro, mas também não carrega nenhuma pagina. com a lista de pessoas q era pra carregar

Comment: Eu testei aqui https://snack.expo.io/B1_sK8N0X utilizando sem o link da api e retornou o erro certinho como deveria ser, unica coisa que alterei foi a função de `componentDidMount` para `componentWillMount`.